# Upload speed capped at 100 Mbps only in LAN

Tags: networking, speed, upload

I have a 500 Mbps Internet plan in Kazakhstan.
In the wired connection, I have full 500 Mbps duplex to **local (the same city) Speedtest servers**:

[image: Speed test screenshot]

However, testing to servers located **outside** of my country (or even inside, those with RTT>17 ms) gives **upload** speeds not higher than **100 Mbps**:

[image: speed test screenshot]

The same behavior is experienced in any real-world use case.

What is interesting, when connected to a **5 GHz Wi-FI**, **upload speeds are not capped at all**. The same server as above:

[image: speed test screenshot]

The same thing happens on **all PCs, all operating systems (Ubuntu, etc.)**.

The cabling is perfect, otherwise, upload speed would not go higher than 100 Mbps on local Speedtest servers.

Could it be that ISP is limiting upload speeds for users on wired connections?
How would they know if a user uses a wired connection? The first TCP/IP layer, **physical layer**, is visible only to my router, so I thought that it is not possible for an ISP to determine that kind of thing.

OS: Windows 10x64
LAN adapter: Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
WLAN adapter: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260

I would be extremely helpful for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you have a regular Wi-Fi router in your home? So that both your wired and wireless traffic would have to go through it.

Comment: Yes, it is a ~50$ regular router. Currently, wired traffic from my PC goes through a GPON modem. Nevertheless, switching wired to the router does not change anything.